# Meteor ios-device: no suitable image found

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

I'm deploying a Meteor app on both android and ios.

```
meteor run android-device ios-device
```

The app starts properly on android, while on ios it gets stuck at the splashscreen, with the following exception:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
Referenced from: 
/var/containers/Bundle/Application/31D76A91-102C-519E-A978-44C752705AF7/MyApp.app/MyApp
Reason: no suitable image found.  
**Did find:**
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/31D76A91-102C-519E-A978-44C752705AF7/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: stat() failed with errno=1
```

It looks like it's looking in the wrong place.
What should I do to get this fixed? (I already tried to create a new project from scratch, clean the build, etc. but no luck)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug that Apple fixed in iOS 10.3.